# ASP.NET - Get GridView width after data is bound

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to do something fairly simple.  I've got a div tag in which my gridview is displayed.  I'd like to set the div width property to the gridview's width property + a few more pixels.  I've tried to access the GridView.Width.Value property in the DataBound and Page_Prerender events but it's always returning 0:

```
protected void Page_Prerender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sWidth = gvUsers.Width.Value.ToString();
    divContactForm.Attributes.Add("style", "width: " + sWidth + " ;");
}
```

I tried the same code in the DataBound event with no luck.

How can I get the GridView's width after the data has been bound to it?

Comment: I don't think this is feasible from the server side because the width of the GridView depends on CSS (font size, padding) and enclosing DOM objects (for example, window size). Why not let your div grow (don't set a width)?

Comment: Well I did set the div width: auto but that puts the div border up against the gv border.

Comment: Just give the div some padding. For example: `style="padding:5px 5px;"`

Comment: Have you tried setting the width property on the div? divContactForm.Width = ... ?

Comment: @JohnPick - This worked, thanks a bunch.  Can you post it as an answer so I can mark it, please.

subt13  - That is what I was trying to do originally in my code (see above) but the GridView.Width is returning 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give the div some padding. For example:

```
style="padding:5px 5px;"
```